# Reactive Form - Multi-dimensional array

Tags: angular

I am attempting to get a multi-dimensional array displayed as a form. I want to be able to specify the values of the x columns and y rows.

I'm not sure what to put in the formControlName for the input box

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mfUquLwCR0lI7vUiAUBe?p=preview

Code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <legend>Settings</legend>
  <form [formGroup]="settingsForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div formArrayName="thresholdArray">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let y_row of settingsForm.controls.thresholdArray.controls; let y = index" >
          <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let x_row of y_row.controls.threshold.controls; let x = index" [formGroupName]="y">
            <div class="well bs-component">
              <label for="inputThreshold" class="col-lg-2 control-label">({{ x }},{{ y }})</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" formControlName="x" class="form-control" id="inputThreshold" placeholder="Threshold" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Typescript/Angular code: (Removed patchValues as it works and not important, you can see it in the plunker example.)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    public settingsForm: FormGroup;
    public NUMBER_OF_X_ROWS: number = 4;
    public NUMBER_OF_Y_ROWS: number = 4;
    public thresholdArray = [];
    public scaleMin;
    public scaleMax;

    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initValues();
        this.buildForm();
        var settingsValues = {
            scaleMin: this.scaleMin,
            scaleMax: this.scaleMax,
            thresholdArray: this.thresholdArray
        }
        this.patchValue(this.settingsForm, settingsValues);

        console.log(this.settingsForm)
    }

    initValues() {
        let x: number;
        let y: number;
        if (localStorage.getItem('scaleMin') === null) {
            this.scaleMin = -140000;
            localStorage.setItem('scaleMin', this.scaleMin);
        } else {
            this.scaleMin = localStorage.getItem('scaleMin');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('scaleMax') === null) {
            this.scaleMax = -90000;
            localStorage.setItem('scaleMax', this.scaleMax);
        } else {
            this.scaleMax = localStorage.getItem('scaleMax');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('thresholdArray') === null) {
            console.log("Initializing thresholdArray");
            for (y = 0; y < this.NUMBER_OF_Y_ROWS; y++) {
                let tempArray = [];
                //this.thresholdArray[y] = [];
                for (x = 0; x < this.NUMBER_OF_X_ROWS; x++) {
                    tempArray.push(-102000)
                }
                this.thresholdArray[y] = { 'threshold': tempArray }
            }
            localStorage.setItem('thresholdArray', JSON.stringify(this.thresholdArray));
        } else {
            this.thresholdArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thresholdArray'));
        }
    }

    buildForm() {
        this.settingsForm = this.fb.group({
            scaleMin: [''],
            scaleMax: [''],
            thresholdArray: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.group({
                    threshold: this.fb.array([
                    ])
                })
            ])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of just looking for something that's already out there that's open source.. For example.. https://valor-software.com/ng2-handsontable/ https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable